# Inconsistent UIToolbar height between iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uitoolbar

For some reason I can't determine, the UIToolbar in my view is a different height on iPhone 6 and 6+ versus the iPhone 5.

My view contains a container view holding a UIPageViewController, whose pages consist of views holding a UIImageView. Under that container view is my UIToolbar view. I set the following UIToolbar view constraint: Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide. For whatever reason, the top of the toolbar is much higher on the iPhone 6.

When I set up the layout in the storyboard editor, my assumption was that the toolbar was a fixed height, and the container view would just stretch to fit the remaining space. However, it seems that the toolbar covers the container, and the image view actually extends under the toolbar and past the screen. What constraints do I need to apply to the toolbar to achieve this?

See screenshots of iPhone 5 (top) and iPhone 6 (bottom).

[image: The iPhone 5 simulator]

[image: The iPhone 6 simulator]

Comment: Are you using AutoLayouts. Which I guess u aint.

Answer (score 0):

Set constraints to your toolbar as shown in this image:

[image]

To remove the gap between container and toolbar, add following constraints to container.

[image]

This will work... try it....

Comment: That does solve the problem of inconsistent height for the UIToolbar, but now there is a gap between the bottom of the container view (or at least the image inside it) and the top of the tool bar. It seems something is limiting the container view to where the top of the tool bar was previously, before I applied the height constraint.

Comment: see my updated answer... And follow : http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1 to get more idea about auto layout .....